# How can I make a userform open by double clicking anywhere in a dynamic range of cells?

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is make a userform (called UserForm1) open up with the data from the active cell's respective row already populated into comboboxes/textboxes by double clicking on any cell in the row. This is also a protected sheet with a password.

I have already made the userform and I have successfully been able to make it populate with the data from the active row through the VBA editor play button. However, I have not been able  get it to work by double clicking a cell in the row.

Other helpful information: This list is dynamic and will be added to and made shorter randomly, so it will need to find the last row with data and make the clickable range from row 2 (the 1st row has headings) down to the last row with data in it.

Here is the code I tried and failed with. I know there is probably a more logical way to do this, but I have been unsuccessful in figuring it out/finding it online.

This code has been placed in the private sheet area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Sheets("Orders").Protect Password:="maintenance", userinterfaceonly:=True

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set Range("A2:K" & Lastrow).Select = Rng

If Target.Address = Rng Then UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

****EDIT****
To reiterate what I'm trying to make happen: when I doubleclick any row with data in it (there could be 2 rows, there could be 50 rows, it depends) I need a userform called **UserComment** to pop up so the user can enter in a comment. I need it to always find the last row of data and include it all in the clickable range. Right now all that happens is essentially nothing. The sheet remains locked, but does not give the "This sheet is protected.." when I double click, only when I try and type something. So the following code recognizes something, but it does not pop up the userform. I'm almost certain it's the exact same as the verified answer posted below (Not including the change in the Sheet name and the userform name), but for some reason it isn't working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Sheets("Open_Orders").Protect Password:="maintenance", userinterfaceonly:=True

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Range("A2:K" & Lastrow)

If Not Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then UserComment.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this raise an error?  `Set Range("A2:K" & Lastrow).Select = Rng`

Comment: When I press the play button/try and double click a cell it brings me to the 3rd line of code and says "Subscript out of range"

Comment: @DavidZemens I have edited it to the best of my ability with what code I have. Still trying to get the userform called UserComment to show up when I double click a cell with data in it (that can have added rows at any time).

Comment: Do you know how to put a breakpoint in your code and then step through it line by line?  Put a breakpoint on the line `Cancel = True`, then double-click in the range. The VBE will let you step line by line through your code using key F8.  You will need to examine the value(s) of the variables being used to check for some inconsistency.  THe likely culprit is that your `If Not Intersect` statement is evaluating to `False`, thus not displaying the form. But you will need to find out what is the `Rng.Address` and the value of `lastRow` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is going to raise an error, your assignment statement is backwards. You assign objects *to* a variable like `Rng`, not the other way around.

`Set Range("A2:K" & Lastrow).Select = Rng`

Also, the `Target.Address` is only ever going to be a single cell range, so you can't do an equivalence test like:

`If Target.Address = Rng Then UserForm1.Show`

Try this instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Sheets("Orders").Protect Password:="maintenance", userinterfaceonly:=True

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Range("A2:K" & Lastrow)

If Not Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

I have verified this is working in an example workbook which is publicly available on my Google Drive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYaDg3S0lTZjRGYnM/edit?usp=sharing).  Double-click *any* of the yellow-highlighted cells and the user form should display like:

[image]

Comment: EDIT: I had a typo in my sheet name. Now it runs, but nothing happens except sometimes it changes the location of the active cell to the 1st cell in the column.

Comment: What runs? Your code? Or My code?  There is nothing in my code which should be changing any selection.  Please use my code.

Comment: I copied and pasted it. But I think it was only changing selection when I accidentally clicked the line separating two cells. So nothing happens when I double click a cell with data in it.

Comment: It no longer tells me that the cells are locked when I double click any cell though, regardless of whether or not it has data in it.

Comment: Nothing in your code *previously* "tells me that the cells are locked", either. Why do you expect it to do so, now?

Comment: I have the sheet password protected. It even still says its protected on the ribbon and it won't let me type anything (gives me the "this sheet is protected...blah"), but nothing pops up when I double click.

Comment: That's because you set `Cancel = True` so the double-click is *not actually happening*.

Comment: So, now that we've verified that this macro *is* displaying the userform as in the scope of your original question, please mark the answer as accepted. If you have additional problems/questions, please ask them as *new* questions.

Comment: Well I disagree that this answered my question. I asked how to get a userform to open and it doesn't open. Or do I really have to ask another question on how to make it open so I can actually see it

Comment: Download [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYaDg3S0lTZjRGYnM/edit?usp=sharing). Double-click in the yellow cells, the user form will display.  Does it not?

Comment: Yes yours works. Mine still doesn't, but thanks for answering the question. I'll have to play around with it.

Comment: If yours doesn't, please *revise* your original question to include the code you are currently attempting to use, and describe exactly what the problem is.  Note: "it's not working" is not a good description of your problem, because nobody but you knows what "working" should actually result in.  Please describe the desired results and contrast those with the *actual* results so that maybe I can help you further.